# Print y Println problema

Tags: java, netbeans, print

el problema que tengo es el siguiente, hace un tiempo instale Netbeans para programar en java, el caso es que cuando compilo un código usando System.out.println("Ejemplo"); si muestra lo muestra en la consola, pero al usar System.out.print("Ejemplo") corre pero no muestra nada.

Comment: Estas observando bien los resultados de la consola? La unica diferencia entre `System.out.println` y `System.out.print` es que el primero introduce una final de linea y retorno de carro

Comment: Agrega el còdigo que tratas de realizar y falla, revisa [ask]